# Intersection of Particles in a Hair Particle System

Tags: particles

I have another question :D

So, currently I am planning to create a short film in Blender for my intermediate project at uni.
I am trying a few things out right now to tackle probable future problems already since my project is not green lit by prof. yet.

I have a few very low poly buildings and want to create a city line for a background shot later.
I use a Particle system with children. The problem I have is that all the buildings intersect and overlap. Looking for a solution, youtube and blendernation were not helpful at all unfortunately.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

My result
[image]

What I am aiming for
[image]
[image]

Btw. if you have any tips or ideas how I could achieve my aim better and nicer and with more fidelity, I would highly appreciate it.

EDIT:

I solved my problem with Blue Noise Addon from Github!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Anyone? No, idea? :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's a way to avoid particle overlapping (except maybe with the help of [this tuto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=15d9yWT5A4Y)?), but you can:

- Create several buildings, texture them. Put them into a collection called Buildings:

[image]

- Create a plane (let's call it Generator) and give it a *Particle System > Hair*, activate the *Advanced* option,  choose the collection you've created as particle, give it an *Emission > Number* of 20:

[image]

- In the *Modifier* panel > *Particle Settings*, click on *Convert*. It will generate instances, reorganize them so that they don't overlap, select all, make the objects single users and join them with <kbd>J</kbd> to create an object:

[image]

- Come back to your Generator plane, generate a new combination, vary the *Emission > Seed* and the *Render > Use Count* settings so that it differs from the previous combination. Do the same as before in order to create a second object. Do it again several times, put all these objects in a collection called Master.
- Create a new plane, subdivide it for example 10 times, give it a *Particle > Hair*, activate the *Advanced* option, choose Master as its particle, give it an *Emission > Number* as high as you have faces on this plane. In *Emission > Source*, deactivate *Random Order*, choose *Particles/Face* = 1.

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for the Idea, that would work but the buildings look to unique in position because they were joined before. Useful for other things though, I will save that! Thank you!

I solved my problem with "blue noise" addon from Github!

Comment: oh ok, great then! Maybe give an answer with this solution so that people know how to fix the problem

Comment: edited the post :D