# Simple buildings

Tags: texturing

I need to create simple buildings. Just pieces comprised of basic shapes, but I really do not want to UV unwrap and apply textures individually. What's the best way to go about this? I'm decent at modeling, but definitely will not have time to unwrap individually. I'm hoping to just use seamless textures.

I was thinking SketchUp might be okay, but I believe the features I'm looking for are only in the paid version.

Comment: There are dozens of ways, what is your end goal? For many dozens, hundreds, or thousands hair particles is one of the best ways with only few objects.

Comment: I'm trying to build a city. Hoping to create a few generic buildings and replicate them throughout.

Comment: I gave an answer here, maybe it will help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194722/intersection-of-particles-in-a-hair-particle-system

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example with some basic shapes and a [hair particle system.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/particles/hair/introduction.html#introduction)

- First create a collection with the shapes that you want your city to made of, here it is just some simple shapes to represent the general idea, that will be scattered arbitrarily across a plane.

[image]

- Group these objects into their own collection with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and give the collection a useful name.
- [Create a *hair particle system*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/particles/particle_system_panel.html#creating-a-particle-system) on your ground (here it is a plane) with the desired number of instances.

In the render section below, [choose collection](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/particles/emitter/render.html#collection) and select the collection that contains your objects. Here are my settings:

[image]

- Next, go into [weight paint mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/weight_paint/index.html#weight-paint), and paint the areas on your ground that you want the buildings to be. Go back to *Object mode* when done.
- Now, in the particle settings, under [*vertex groups*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/particles/emitter/vertex_groups.html#vertex-groups) add the new group available under density. Rename it if you'd like, or leave as default "Group".

[image]

You should end up with something like this (again arbitrary placement):

[image]

As for random placement of material, a method I like to use is a node tree like below:

[image]
<sup>*click to enlarge*</sup>

The Principled Nodes can be replaced with anything, what is crucial in this setup is the coloramps (set to constant interpolation)and the object info/ random. They can be chained for as long you like to give random results for particle systems and linked mesh objects.

[image]